# How to swipe back to previous view while sheet is presented?

Tags: ios, swiftui

My goal is to swipe back to previous view. However, the sheet prevent that.

```
struct ContentViewViewOne: View {
    init() {
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("hello world")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented: Bool
    @State private var selection: PresentationDetent
    
    init(isPresented: Bool = true, selection: PresentationDetent = .medium) {
        self._isPresented = State(wrappedValue: isPresented)
        self._selection = State(wrappedValue: selection)
        
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("hello")
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            VStack {
                Text("world")
                    .presentationDetents([.medium, .large], selection: $selection)
                    .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
                    .presentationDragIndicator(.hidden)
                
                Button {
                    isPresented = false
                } label: {
                    Text("start")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: Binding(
            get: { !isPresented },
            set: { isPresented = !$0 }
        ), destination: {
            NavigationLazyView {
                ContentViewViewOne()
            }
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink {
                ContentView()
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            } label: {
                Text("feature 1")
            }
        }
    }
}
```